# Create MIPS Binary Search Tree Struct

Tags: mips

How do I create a struct in MIPS using this C code? I wrote something up but I don't know if that is how it is done. I am trying to create a binary search tree but can't seem to figure out how to create the struct. Someone please help

```
struct BSTNode
{
struct BSTNode *left;
struct BSTNode *right;
int val;
};
```

Like this?

```
node:
 subu $sp, $sp, 32 
 sw $ra, 28($sp) 
 sw $fp, 24($sp) 
 sw $s0, 20($sp) 
 sw $s1, 16($sp) 
 sw $s2, 12($sp) 
 sw $s3, 8($sp) 
 addu $fp, $sp, 32 
 # capture the parameters: 

 addi $s0, $a0, 0 # $s0 = value
 addi $s1, $a1, 0 # $s1 = left
 addi $s2, $a2, 0 # $s2 = right

 li $a0, 12 # it needs 12 bytes for a new node. 
 li $v0, 9 # sbrk is syscall 9. 
 syscall 
 addi $s3, $v0, 0

 beqz $s3, main_TESTCASE_ERR_MSG1

 sw $s0, 0($s3) # node->number = number 
 sw $s1, 4($s3) # node->left = left 
 sw $s2, 8($s3) # node->right = right 

 move $v0, $s3 # put return value input into v0. 
 # release the stack frame: 
 lw $ra, 28($sp) # restore the Return Address. 
 lw $fp, 24($sp) # restore the Frame Poinputer. 
 lw $s0, 20($sp) # restore $s0. 
 lw $s1, 16($sp) # restore $s1. 
 lw $s2, 12($sp) # restore $s2. 
 lw $s3, 8($sp) # restore $s3. 
 addu $sp, $sp, 32 # restore the Stack Poinputer. 
 jr $ra # return. 
 ## end of node
```

Answer (score 2):

Your basic struct code is correct. You can do it the way you have [with the hardwired offsets from the base register].

But, in asm, structs are usually defined using "equates". These fall under the category of *assembler directives* (i.e. like `.text` or `.data`) that tell the assembler to "do something" but not generate code.

These are the asm equivalent of C's `#define` or `enum`. Virtually all assemblers have some form of this. For example, some arches/assemblers use `EQU`

These allow you to refer to the offsets within the struct by name. The advantages are:

1. It saves some of the drudge
2. Can prevent mistakes where the wrong offset is inadvertently used (e.g. the struct offsets in your code don't match the offsets of the C struct you provided)
3. Makes the code a bit more self documenting and readable.

I often include the C struct as a top comment block in the asm code. Here is how to use the equates. I've included equate definitions for both `mars` and `spim`. Use one or the other [as they're not compatible]:

```
# C struct:
#   struct BSTNode {
#       struct BSTNode *left;
#       struct BSTNode *right;
#       int val;
#   };

# BSTNode struct (if using mars)
    .eqv    left            0
    .eqv    right           4
    .eqv    val             8
    .eqv    sizeof_node     12

# BSTNode struct (if using spim)
    left            =       0
    right           =       4
    val             =       8
    sizeof_node     =       12

    # ...

    li      $a0,sizeof_node         # number of bytes for new node
    li      $v0,9                   # sbrk is syscall 9.
    syscall
    addi    $s3,$v0,0

    beqz    $s3,main_TESTCASE_ERR_MSG1

    sw      $s0,val($s3)            # node->val = number
    sw      $s1,left($s3)           # node->left = left
    sw      $s2,right($s3)          # node->right = right
```